# Although wireshark see ping response, ping program does not receive response if there is a unreachable deafult route in the routing table

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, routing

This particular computer is running with centos and has three interfaces; eth0, eth1 and eth2. NetLan is a bridge interface with eth0, tap0 and tap1 interfaces. The bridge interface has a static ip address, 192.168.1.100.

The gateway 192.168.1.1 is turned off for some reason eth2 address is 10.1.10.182 and is connected to internet via 10.1.10.1 eth1.5 is a VLAN interface with 192.168.97.5 address

When I ping 8.8.8.8 from centos machine, ping does not receive response. However, wireshark see response from the 8.8.8.8.

Can anyone shed some light.

Route table:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface

0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 NetLan
0.0.0.0 10.1.10.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth2
0.0.0.0 10.1.10.1 0.0.0.0 UG 100 0 0 eth2
10.1.10.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 100 0 0 eth2
192.168.1.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 NetLan
192.168.97.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth1.5
192.168.98.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 tun0
192.168.98.2 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 tun1
192.168.98.3 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 tun2
192.168.122.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 virbr0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have three default routes. In the context this simply isn't going to work.

By definition you can only have one default route (it's the route taken *by default* if there is no explicit route).

Fix that and you may find your networking starts to behave.